# Start camera activity in a thread and it runs twice

Tags: android

I am using a thread, (tested Runnable, Asynch) to implement a delay and then start camera activity, but the problem is after taking a pic and returing back camera is launched again, so my camera activity is lunched twice, what could be the sol. I have used Runnable as well for implementing thread. Thanks.

```
                  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                  Thread_as obj=new Threads_as();
                  obj.execute("");
                   }
                      ............

                  doInBackground(){
                  int timer=0;
            while(timer<2000)
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                timer+=100;
            }}
   onPostExecute(){
    Intent it=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);          
        startActivity(it);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Do you run the AsyncTask every time the original activity is started?

Comment: main activty only runs single time in which this code is called.

Comment: could you post a little more of the activity that starts the camera?

Comment: It is possible your activity gets destroyed while running the camera task, meaning that when you return from the camera it will be recreated and the onCreate function will be called again, thus resulting in another call to the camera after 2 seconds.
You can easily test to see if this happens by adding a logging line to your code and looking for it in the LogCat console:
`Log.d("MyActivity", "onCreating");`

Comment: i have also tried using boolean so that activity does not run it twice but no solution, it runs twice.

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by using same boolean technique but by shared preferences, storing yes or no in preferences and wraping around new intent.

                  String val=sharedPref.getString(...);
                  if(val.equals("true"))
                    { launch new intent
                      sharedPrefEditor.putstring("..","false");
                      sharedPrefEditor.commit();
                     }

it solved the problem and camera wil not run twice.
Thanks.